# How to instantiate a UITableViewCell from a nib

Tags: iphone, uikit, uitableview

One can add a tableviewcell in the nib of its tableviewcontroller, but how do you get to it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple has a great explanation on how to do this in [the table view programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18)

Comment: The link return: 404 HTTP_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @Beppe probably because it's a 3 1/2 year old answer. I just updated the link though, try again.

Comment: Thanks, googling "table view programming guide" is not that difficult, my comment was just to advise users that the link was broken and no actual update was needed, but I really appreciate your following up such an old answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two good articles on this (From Bill Dudney and Jeff LaMarche):

http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/uitableview_from_a_nib_file

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/09/table-view-cells-in-interface-builder.html